# i keep getting type-related errors

Tags: c, scanf

I'm writing this program for my homework and i keep getting type errors. To my knowledge %d reads integer which is in this case the variable x and %lf reads double " variable f"

i've tried to remove "\n" in scanf() function as it was requested in other Questions

```
int x=0;
int l=0;
double f=0;
printf("Geben Sie eine ganze Zahl");
scanf("%d",x);
printf("Geben Sie eine reele Zahl");
scanf("%lf",f);
l=-1;
char r[1]="";
char s[1]="";
  while(l !=1){
    printf("Geben Sie ein Zeichen");
    scanf("%s",r);
    l=strlen(r);
}
return 0;
```

**Errors:**

```
C:/Users/---(9): warning in format string of scanf(): the conversion %d expects type int* but given type is int (argument 1).
C:/Users/---(11): warning in format string of scanf(): the conversion %lf expects type double* but given type is double (argument 1).
```

Comment: The error messages are clear enough. Why do not you read them?! Use scanf("%d",&x); and scanf("%lf",&f);

Comment: Although you didn't ask,   `scanf("%s", r)` gives undefined behaviour if `r` is an array with one element (as it is in your code) and the user enters any non-whitespace character (like `'A'`) followed by a newline.    The `%s` format as-is causes `scanf()` to ASSUME the array passed is long enough to hold a string the user enters, plus a following nul character.   Providing an array that does not satisfy that assumption gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter to prevent that from happening i used the While Loop and a 1-character string instead of a character.

Comment: @user3253021 - that doesn't fix it.   If the user enters the letter `A` followed by anything (even a newline, or a space, or a character then a space),  `scanf()` will write more than one character to the array.   For an array with one element, that gives undefined behaviour.    `strlen(r)` will also have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The messages are not clear to somebody who has not learned that `int*` means a pointer to an `int`. To their eye, the `*` is some cryptic character the computer inserted.

Answer (score 5):

It's like the warning says: The function is expecting pointers to the types that you're giving it. Fix it by putting a `&` before the variable, which makes it pass the address instead:

```
printf("Geben Sie eine ganze Zahl");
scanf("%d", &x);
printf("Geben Sie eine reele Zahl");
scanf("%lf", &f);
```

There's also an issue with how you're reading in characters. This here

```
char r[1] = "";
char s[1] = "";
```

Makes two arrays that contain nothing else than a null terminator. It doesn't have any capacity to read in a non-empty string, which you're doing here:

```
scanf("%s", r);
```

It's unclear whether you're trying to read in a whole string or just a character, as your output implies. For just one character, your code should look like this:

```
char r;
scanf("%c", &r);
```

And for a whole string:

```
char r[20]; // can hold 19 chars plus a null terminator
scanf("%19s", r);
```

Adjust those sizes to match the length of the string that you need to read.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` requires the memory address of the variable to assign the value. and you need to specify the address with an ampersand before the variable like `&variable` . There's the problem. But when working with strings you don't need that, remember strings are array of characters. So when addressing a string you don't address a variable, you give the first index of the array.So you don't add ampersand there.

```
int x=0;
int l=0;
double f=0;

printf("Geben Sie eine ganze Zahl");

scanf("%d",&x);

printf("Geben Sie eine reele Zahl");

scanf("%lf",&f);

l=-1;
char r[1]="";
char s[1]="";
while(l !=1){
    printf("Geben Sie ein Zeichen");
    scanf("%s",r);
    l=strlen(r);
}
return 0;
```

and why are you taking 1 character as a string? you could just do it this way

```
char r='';
while( r==''){
     scanf("%c",&r);
}
```